# How can I trigger some code when a field is changed, but before the record is saved?

Tags: trigger

I want to detect when a certain field has been changed in the browser, and run some code to clean up the text in that field so the user can see the clean version before saving the changes to the record.

All I can find is trigger functionality for when the actual record in the database is changing, but I want to run code when the DOM changes on a standard object's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a visualforce page you can achieve it using client side javascript/jQuery. Onchange you can call your script and do cleanup or modify value.

If it is not a visualforce page you will have to override with a visualforce page so that you can execute client side javascript.

Comment: How can I override it with a VF page that is identical to the original (except that it is a VF page)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to create a Visualforce page with Javascript to replace the standard object's edit page.